# Program crashes after constructor is called

Tags: c++, class, pointers, tree, nodes

```
 template<class item_type>  struct node{
     item_type x;
     node<item_type> *left;
     node<item_type> *right;
     int Get_Height();
     int Get_Num_Nodes();  };

 template<class item_type, class param>  class Tree{
        node<item_type> *root;
    public: // some functions
      Tree(int roo);
```

I have a Tree class that takes nodes as its leaves. Tree(int roo) is the constructor.

```
template<class item_type, class param>
Tree<item_type, param>::Tree(int roo)
{
    this->root->x=roo;
    this->root->left=NULL;
    this->root->right=NULL;
}
```

This is the implimentation of the constructor. I have also tried omitting the `root->left=NULL` and same with right and both of them at the same time, as well as having no constructor and using the default one.

All of which seem to crash my program when I run `Tree<int, int> durr(1);` in `main()`

I can't seem to see a problem and I am a novice programmer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `root` is uninitialized.

Comment: @blub That's kinda a misnomer. In release builds, root probably just points to garbage rather that NULL.

Comment: @blub, No, it is uninitialized. Default-initialization for fundamental types is no initialization.

Comment: @chris wow, that was a stupid error, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `*root` with `this->root = new node<item_type>`